# drop down .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a drop down that is NOT keeping the value that I select. I already check to True the EnableViewState and nothing yet.
What may be missing here? Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you filling the drop down? Statically on the page? Dynamically in the Code Behind?

Comment: post some code! it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're filling it in the `Page_Load()`, it will get overwritten each time the page loads.  If you want the user selection to persist, fill it in the `Page_Init()`.   The viewstate is applied in between the Page_Load and the Page_Init, so this will ensure proper order of execution.

For more info, look up the Page Lifecycle for ASsp.Net.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. 
Good to re-think this facts which I was doing but my problem was that
I was assigning a Request in the page load that was carrying nothing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was assigning a Request in the page load that was carrying nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Check your Page_Load method.  Make sure when you populate it and select the default value it is inside an

```
if(!IsPostBack) { .. . . }
```

You could be accidentally setting it on each post back, which is why it seems like it is not retaining its value.

Comment: I've made this mistake before.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was assigning a Request in the page load that was carrying nothing.

Answer (score 0):

where are you binding your Dropsown list? Make sure that you do following:

if(!IsPostBack)

{

//Do your data binding here

}